# Cannot edit post meta fields with rest API

Tags: custom-field, post-meta, rest-api, api, python

I am using python to send POST requests to `/wp-json/wp/v2/< post type >/< post id >`. This successfully updates standard fields such as title, content etc. However I am unable to make any changes to the custom theme meta fields structured like

```
"post_meta":{
    "meta_1":[],
     .
     .
     "meta_n":[]
}.
```

When I make a `GET` request to the same endpoint, the post meta fields are returned so I don't think this is an issue with the fields not being registered?

Thanks

Comment: Post meta values are strings, it doesn't make sense to pass a `[]`, and the meta fields do need to be registered, It looks like you're saving structured data in post meta, and are unaware that WP serialises non-string values via the PHP `serialize` function, and the `maybe_deserialize` function. It would be simpler and easier to store individual values. Also note that post meta keys are not unique, you can have multiple post meta key/value pairs with the same key on a post.

Comment: Also, did you check the message in the response the REST API gave when you tried to update the post meta values?

Comment: Using the endpoint above the API responds with the post data showing the changed title and content but no change to the meta. The post response json shows the meta values as a list of strings.

Comment: Did you register any of the meta values? If so please update the code to include that registration. If not, add registration code and try again

Comment: The post type was added as part of a theme, so not registered by me. I have been able to successfully create these posts with included meta fields in the request. However I am not able to edit the meta of the existing posts.

Comment: That doesn't mean you can't register the meta values, you can just use a plugin or a child theme of your own creation to make the call, it has nothing to do with the registration of post types: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_meta/, _but have you contacted the theme vendor support? 3rd party theme dev support is off topic here_

Comment: where should I add this function? inside funcitons.php?

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, in a child theme or a plugin of your own creation. You should not modify the main theme. Again though ***Have you contacted the support route for the theme? 3rd party theme dev support is Off Topic here***

Comment: theme support are completely useless

Comment: is this correct:
`
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'register_post_meta_agent');
function register_post_meta_agent(){
 register_post_meta( 'agent', 'agent_meta', array(
        'object_subtype'    => 'agent',
        'type'              => 'array',
        'description'       => '',
        'default'           => '',
        'single'            => false,
        'show_in_rest'      => true,
    ) );
} 
`

Comment: I'm sorry your interactions with their theme support weren't productive, but that doesn't mean our scope has changed or that special exceptions can be made for this specific question. There is an extremely high chance that this question can never be solved using generic WordPress knowledge, and that specialist knowledge of the theme you are using is necessary, or at least a full copy of the code is necessary or reproduction of the issue.

Comment: I appreciate that - I have done some digging around and found this code registering the fields.
`
    add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'agent_rest_api_field' );
    function agent_rest_api_field() {
        register_rest_field( 'agent', 'agent_meta', array(
            'get_callback' => 'get_rest_api_agent_meta'
        ) );
    }
    function get_rest_api_agent_meta( $object ) {
        $post_id = $object['id'];
        $agent_meta = get_post_meta( $post_id );
        $agent_meta = apply_filters( 'agent_rest_api_meta', $agent_meta );
        return $agent_meta;
    }
`

Comment: Do I need to an update_callback function to the code above?